# display thumbnail images from URL’s in tableVeiw Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, custom-cell

I want to display thumbnail images from URL’s in every tableView cell. it is working fine.
But the problem is when I scroll is causes some GUI delays. I know it is because of URL request every time I scroll or every time new cell created.
Is there any better way to do it, that does not cause any UI delays.

I'm using the following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: WelcomeCell = WelcomeCell();
    cell = self.tblViewStudent.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WelcomeCell") as WelcomeCell

    if news != nil {
    if news.count > 0 {
        var objNews = News();
        objNews = news.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as News;

        cell.lblNewsSubject.text = objNews.subject;
        cell.lblNewsTime.text = objNews.created_at;
        cell.lblNewsSummery.text = objNews.summery;

        let url = NSURL(string: objNews.thumbnailURL)
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) 
        cell.viewImageThumbnail.image = UIImage(data: data!);
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }

    }
    return cell;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I m waiting for your reply

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 0):

Save the  thumbnail images from URL’s in `Array` or `Mutable Array` when your class first load then place the image from array into your `cell.viewImageThumbnail.image`

Answer (score 0):

Just use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

For displaying images in table view cells just do:

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Here we use the new provided sd_setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
    return cell;
}
```